# Drawing on Shabbes: product recommendation?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, product-recommendation, art, melacha-tzoveya

I have two young children, one of whom (aged six) loves drawing. Sadly, she often professed to hate Shabbes, given that she cannot draw for the entire day, and I have been looking for a kosher alternative.

One of the things that we have been using is a booklet with pictures that only reveal their colours under water. Using a special applicator, she ‘paints’ the pages with water and the images come to life, but fade back to obscurity as they dry. It’s cute, but it’s not really satisfying her urge to draw.

Are there halakhically permitted products that we can use? Something using light, or iron filings, or sand - with the understanding that it will be for pictures and not for writing. Sources please for the legitimacy of anything; it needs to be 100% kosher for Shabbes.

Comment: the alternative you mentioned (the booklet with water) still sounds like it would be ossur under tzevo

Comment: @ezra have you ever seen them? I don't see how it's tzovea

Comment: @ezra - The colours are already there. The water just makes them appear vibrant, and they fade again as the page dries.

Comment: You should ask a rav about your case. Since this is a question of chinuch, there might be room for leniency in certain cases even if something would not be permitted for an adult (like with lego for boys according to Rav Moshe).

Comment: @DoubleAA even a mug that color-changes when heated would be tzovea iirc, and these colors are permanent

Comment: @Esther that doesn't sound like a remotely similar case

Comment: @DoubleAA why is it different? Just noticed these images are temporary as well. You have a mug that temporarily displays an image when it's hot, and a paper that temporarily displays an image when it's wet. I don't see the difference.

Comment: @Esther have you ever seen them?

Comment: @DoubleAA what, the mug or the water-activated pictures? I believe I've seen both, but I definitely know what both are. The point is that there is an image, but it isn't visible until you *do something*, and then it's only temporarily visible. These characteristics are the same for the mug and the picture. What is different?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that someone could see both these things and not see them as wildly different, hence I suspect we are not talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Esther Going to have to agree with DoubleAA here. My daughter's coloring books show the entire image except for the colors. Only colors appear when she gets it wet, the black lines which actually make up the picture are always visible and never change The mugs show no image at all until heat is added.

Comment: @Aaron oh, so the difference is the lines, then. I see the difference, but I'm not convinced it matters. You might want to ask a knowledgeable rabbi to be sure.

Comment: קטן אוכל נבלות אין בית דין מצווים להפרישו

Comment: I don't see the lines as a primary difference. It's just physically a totally different situation. @Esther

Comment: You should really ask a Rabbi. The problem is, the prohibition of drawing is not only with a pen, its to make shapes or pictures with anything - even sand. Also this sounds like more of a chinuch question than a halacha question.

Comment: You have to make shabbos fun for her, so she doesn't hate it. Do other stuff she enjoys. Maybe get her a special shabbos toy she would really like. Give her extra treats. Etc. You want to make her love shabbos, not to make her not hate it.

Comment: @ezra in this case the color is already there underneath. By wetting a thin white cloth covering you make it temporarily semi transparent (as we all know happens to wet white clothing). No coloring happens at all with these toys.

Comment: Toys on Shabbat:
https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5761-kisavo/
https://outorah.org/p/80534/

Answer (score 3):

First of all, @Kovy Jacob's comment deserves to be highlighted:

"You have to make shabbos fun for her, so she doesn't hate it. Do other stuff she enjoys. Maybe get her a special shabbos toy she would really like. Give her extra treats. Etc. You want to make her love shabbos, not to make her not hate it."

As to the substantive issue: A game such as Bananagrams is mutar (https://outorah.org/p/51876/) - i.e., there's no problem putting letters together to form a word, as long as they're not attached to each other or to a board. So it would seem that the same could apply to, say, beads or small blocks: let her put them together, on the table or the floor or whatever (again, not attached to each other or to anything), to form a picture. (And if you can provide her a space to do so where it won't be disarranged until after Shabbos, then you'll be able to take a photo of it and thus preserve it for the future.)

To be sure, as N.T. mentioned in a comment, ask a rav, to make sure this comparison is correct, and to see if there are still better alternatives.